# Can I improve data.table performance with inequality condition

Tags: r, performance, time-series, data.table

I am trying to improve performance in the following code. The objective is to find the most recent observation as of a given time (in this case `from_time + 5000`) for each `id`:

```
library(data.table)

from_time <- Sys.time()
d <- cumsum(sample(c(0.02, 0.1, 0.2), 200000, TRUE))
ts <- from_time + d
DF <- expand.grid(t = ts, id = 1:300)
N <- nrow(DF)

DT = data.table(t = DF$t,
                id = DF$id,
                x = sample(100L, N, TRUE),
                y = sample(1000L, N, TRUE),
                z = rnorm(N))

key(DT) # NULL

system.time(
    result <- DT[
        t <= from_time + 5000
        , .SD[order(-t), .(x, y, z)][1]
        , by = .(id)
    ]
)
```

This gave me:

```
user  system elapsed 
1.78    0.78    1.72
```

I tried adding a key on `id` and `t` but it doesn't seem to help:

```
setkey(DT, id, t)
key(DT) #[1] "id" "t" 

system.time(
    result <- DT[
        t <= from_time + 5000
        , .SD[order(-t), .(x, y, z)][1]
        , by = .(id)
    ]
)


user  system elapsed 
1.90    0.31    1.83
```

Am I right to think that the key did not improve performance? Is there a way to improve performance here?

Answer (score 2):

One area for improved performance is when you order by `t`.  You don't want/need to order `t` within each .SD. You could try something like this instead:

```
DT[t<=(from_time+5000)][order(-t),first(.SD),by=id][, t:=NULL]
```

Answer (score 2):

The key did not improve performance because the expression `order(-t)` in `i` (`SD[order(-t), .(x, y, z)]`) destroys the key that you set. Instead, do not reorder the data after setting the key and use the function `last` to benefit from internal optimization:

```
library(data.table)

setkey(DT, id, t)

system.time(DT[t <= from_time + 5000, last(.SD), id][, !"t"])

user  system elapsed 
0.49    0.01    0.36
```